# Не могу подключится к SQL SERVER 2012 java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Пытаюсь подключится к удаленной базе данных на сервере. Выдает ошибку:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:291)
at sqlConnection.dbConnect(sqlConnection.java:18)
at sqlConnection.main(sqlConnection.java:9)
```

Сам код моего подключения выглядит так:

```
public class sqlConnection {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sqlConnection connServer = new sqlConnection();
    connServer.dbConnect("jdbc:sqlserver://UAKYI1DWH01;databaseName=sms_ws;integratedSecurity=true;",
            "<user>",
            "<password>");
}

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        }
```

Подскажите, что я упустил? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Класс **SQLServerDriver** не найден, каким образом вы добавили драйва в проект?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S => + => import module => Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.4 for SQL Server => sqljdbc_6.4

Comment: В принципе, весь код после строки 18 к проблеме не относится. Пример кода можно составить из одной строчки (`Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");`) в методе `main`. Напишите подробнее как запускаете проект.

Comment: Пишу подключение, добавляю jdbc jar файлы, запускаю

Comment: Это в IntelliJ? Попробуйте добавить JAR файл в Libraries

Comment: Да, в Intellij. Добавил, тот же самый эффект

Comment: `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")` вызывается ДО вызова `dbConnect`? Т.е. в конструкторе класса? Попробуйте перенести `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")`  перед вызовом  `dbConnect`. Т.е. все сделайте в `main`